# Alpine js x-on expressions

Tags: alpine.js

In an Alpine JS x-on event handler for click, I get a behavior I don't understand. This works fine:

```
x-on:click="
    ancestor = trail[index];
    trail = trail.slice(0, index);
    loading = true;
    collection = await getCollection(ancestor.id)
    loading = false;
"
```

but this

```
x-on:click="
    if (item.type === 'Collection') {
        trail.push({
            id: collection.id,
            label: collection.label.sv[0]
        });
        collection = await getCollection(item.id)
    } else {
        image.present = true;
        image.id = item.id
    }
"
```

only works if I precede the **if** expression with e.g. a console.log

```
console.log(`--- Item type: ${item.type}`);
```

What is special about **if**? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an async function call in the `if` block, so the whole block needs to be awaitable. Since the business logic is already too complex for one line, it would be better to create a separate method for it in a component with [`Alpine.data()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data), and call it in the `@click` directive.

```
<div x-data="MyComponent()">
  <button @click="getItems">Get items</button>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('MyComponent', () => ({
    // Data definitions
    trail: [],
    item: {},
    image: {},
    collection: {},

    async getItems() {
      if (this.item.type === 'Collection') {
        this.trail.push({
          id: this.collection.id,
          label: this.collection.label.sv[0]
        })
        this.collection = await getCollection(this.item.id)
      } else {
        this.image.present = true
        this.image.id = this.item.id
      }
    }
  }))
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine and I eventually moved the Alpine.data() call out to an external JS file to further reduce the amount of code in the HTML.